# How do we prevent Microsoft Policy Platform Local Authority service from stopping?

Tags: webserver, windows-server-2012, authentication, windows-server, windows-services

After some extensive research into a problem that cropped up on some systems after a Windows update, we're seeing the following service stop:

Microsoft Policy Platform Local Authority

We believe this is causing authentication failures to certain shares and servers.   As a stopgap, we are now running a service that monitors *this* service, sends a notice when it goes down, and reactivates it.  Our problems in the related web applications haven't occurred since.  Unfortunately, this monitor is firing off 24-30 times per day.  How can we keep this service running consistently?

**Server version is Windows Server 2012 R2**

Comment: Which Windows version?

Comment: OOPS!  I updated the question.